# Excel Conditional Formatting - Ignore rows with blank first cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need to compare two sheets using Conditional Formatting.

Sheet 1 looks like this:

[[image]

Sheet 2 looks like this:

[[image]

Both sheets have 7 projects (with 2 projects without Project ID’s). These projects appear in different order on both sheets, but they are essentially same projects (Projects can be identified by their Project ID AND Activity). Also, some project’s Amount changed in sheet 2.

Currently, I am using this formula to highlight projects with different Amounts on sheet 1 and 2.

```
  =SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C, Sheet1!A:A, A2, Sheet1!B:B, B2)<>C2
```

But, as you can see, this formula will also highlight row 7 and 8. I want the formula to ignore the projects without Project IDs (doesn’t matter the amount changed or not, ignore them). But I am not sure how to do that in conditional formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AND` and add the condition that column A not be blank:

```
=AND(SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C, Sheet1!A:A, A2, Sheet1!B:B, B2)<>C2,A2<>"")
```